# NSStroyboards and setting NSManagedObjectContext on a custom controller before it loads nib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-yosemite

Just so we are clear this is a question relating to OSX and 10.10... not iOS storyboards.

I have a custom window controller which is the main window for the storyboard.  The app is document based so I can't use the well established singleton method for accessing the MOC (every document has its own stack).

So the other option is to pass the MOC as a variable to all the controllers thats need it. I've done this prior to using storyboards by creating a custom initialiser for the controller and instantiating the controller myself. This means that the controller has its MOC variable set by the time the controller loads the contents of its view, and therefore the views can load their data sources etc all off the back of being loaded by the controller.

Now that I am using storyboards I am unsure as to how to pass the MOC on before the nib is actually loaded. It not a huge problem, but say for instance one of my views was a table view, when it loads its going to try and load its data, which of course it can’t because the MOC is still nil. I can just set it after its been loaded and then ask the tableview to reload its data but this seems a bit of a fudge for something that was previously elegant... there must be a way of setting up the controller before it loads its views right?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's sample code for Lister overwrites setDocument: on the window controller and sets what it needs to there. Its not quite what I was hoping for but its less clunky than what I was doing before.

So I end up with something that looks like this in my window controller:

```
- (void)setDocument:(NSPersistentDocument *)document {
   [super setDocument:document];

   self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;

   NSSplitViewController *splitVC = (NSSplitViewController*)self.contentViewController;
   NSSplitViewItem *leftPane = [[splitVC splitViewItems]firstObject];
   NSSplitViewItem *rightPane = [[splitVC splitViewItems]lastObject];

   StaffSidebarViewController *staffSideBarVC = (StaffSidebarViewController*)[leftPane viewController];
   EventsViewController *eventsViewVC = (EventsViewController*)[rightPane viewController];

   staffSideBarVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
   eventsViewVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

   [staffSideBarVC.tableView reloadData];
   [eventsViewVC.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Would still appreciate any thoughts on this. Thanks.